# Unterschied zwischen Einrichtung und Vorrichtung

Tags: difference

I möchte gern wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen *Einrichtung* und *Vorrichtung* ist.

Sind das immer Geräte oder Produkte?

Comment: Schon im Wörterbuch nachgeschaut?

Comment: These two words are rather different and also have different translations into English. Could you maybe point out a special case (an English sentence to be translated, etc.) to illustrate where you run into problem with these words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things that are called Einrichtung or Vorrichtung. However, in the context of **technical equipment** - which your question suggests - you may take as a rule of thumb:

*Einrichtung* would be a larger, usually complex piece of equipment.

*Vorrichtung* tends to be typcially a smaller, less complex piece of equipment.

Imagine you are taking a tour through a mill, and the miller explains:

> Diese Einrichtung hier dient der Säuberung des Getreides. Die Einrichtung ist groß und komplex und geht über drei Stockwerke. Sie enthält eine Vorrichtung zum Ausblasen der Spelzen, eine Vorrichtung zum Sieben, und viele weitere Vorrichtungen.

It would not be a gross mistake if the miller swaped the two terms; everybody would understand him anyway; but typcial usage would be *Einrichtung* for the larger thing, and *Vorrichtung* for the smaller thing.

An edging machine (used e.g. by tinsmiths, German: Abkantmaschine), which is an instrument with basically one single purpose, would rather be called a *Vorrichtung*. Whereas a multifunctional table saw, router and jointer in a woodworking shop would better be called *Einrichtung* (but its individual mono-functional elements *Vorrichtung*).

(There are other meanings of *Einrichtung*, e.g. *institution*, *establishing*, as well as *furniture and decoration*, but in the context of your question we discuss solely *Einrichtung* as technical equipment here.)

Comment: That was my point, in the technical domain! Danke :)

Answer (score 2):

**Einrichtung** und **Vorrichtung** sind einander sehr ähnlich. Beides beschreibt die *Ausstattung* eines anderen Teils.

> Die Einrichtung deiner Wohnung ist sehr schön.

*Vorrichtung* betont, dass es sich bei der Einrichtung um etwas mit einer technischen Funktion handelt.

> An dieser Zange gibt es eine Vorrichtung zum Schneiden von Drähten.
>
> An der Gardine gibt es eine Vorrichtung zum Raffen.